# Java Watchdog monitoring

Tags: java, linux, windows, monitoring

I am trying to develop a watchdog in java (windows and linux) who will operate in two ways:

1) Passive monitoring.

After the process finish his job, the watchdog need to check with which return value the process finished. (exit(1), exit(0)...)

2) Active monitoring.

The process need to "touch" a file who belongs to him every interval(x).
The watchdog will check every interval (y) if the process "touch" his file by checking the file stamp.
If the process didn't touch the file, the watchdog will try to send a signal to the process for touching the file.
The active monitoring purpose is to kill processes with deadlock.

The watchdog will start all the processes.

1) How can I send the jvm of a process signal? one signal is a "reminder" for the process to touch the file.
The other signal is to kill the process.

2) How can I implement the idea on threads?

3) There is any API in Java that I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. you can 'signal' a process by writing/reading from the process int/outputstream
2. well, implement te thread (see below)
3. i don't know...

maybe this snippet helps

```
public class ProcessTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProcessTest().start();
    }

    private void start() {
        startWatchDog();
        startProcess();
    }

    private boolean abortCondition = false;
    private int watchDogTSleepTime = 3000; //3 sek
    private void startWatchDog() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(!abortCondition){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(watchDogTSleepTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //check the file touch
                    boolean ok = checkFileTouch();

                    try {
                        //send signals to the process
                        outStream.write("signal".getBytes() );
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //if you want, you might try to kill the process
                    process.destroy();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread watchDog = new Thread(r);
        watchDog.start();
        //watchDog.setDaemon(true); //maybe
    }

    private boolean checkFileTouch(){
        //...
        return false;
    }

    private InputStream inStream;
    private OutputStream outStream;
    private Process process;
    private void startProcess() {       
        String[] cmd = new String[]{"foo.exe", "para1", "param2"};
        try {
            //create and start the process
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            inStream = process.getInputStream();
            outStream = process.getOutputStream();          
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```